# OnInit and AfterViewInit Called after window resize or click event?

Tags: angular

I have a component which is loaded using DCL.The problem is that this component loads correctly but the OnInit and AfterViewInit events are not fired.It gets called when I resize the window or click on the screen somewhere.Because of this the template is not displayed.Can somebody please tell me how can i solve this issue? I tried using ngZone too but it is not working.

Below is the code for `AfterViewInit` which does not get called at all

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  const DynamicComponent: any = this.DCLLoader.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentToLoad);
  this.DynamicComponentLoader.clear();
  let dynamicComp: any = this.DynamicComponentLoader.createComponent(DynamicComponent‌​);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code to look and what is dcl?

Comment: the AfterviewInit event doesnot Fire at all.
`ngAfterViewInit() {
      const DynamicComponent: any = this.DCLLoader.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentToLoad);
      this.DynamicComponentLoader.clear();
      let dynamicComp: any = this.DynamicComponentLoader.createComponent(DynamicComponent);
  }`

Comment: I moved it to the queston

Comment: Thanks @AniruddhaDas .this is exactly how i load the component dynamically.I can see console statement placed in my constructor but the console statement in afterviewinit does not execute sometimes.It fires if i make some changes like window resize or changing tab or clicking on window